# How can a WCF client consume a multipart/related java webservice reponse?

Tags: c#, java, wcf, response, content-type

I wrote **a WCF C# client** that consumes a Java webservice:

```
var client = new abcClient("abc");
var response = client.AbcTransaction(msg);
```

The **WCF binding info** from web.config is:

```
<customBinding>
 <binding name="abcSOAP">
  <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
  <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
 </binding>
</customBinding>
```

It looks pretty straight-forward, right? ...And indeed, SoapFaults are easy to consume:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 783
Content-Type: application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 14:06:18 GMT

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap:Body><soap:Fault>...
```

However, the webservice sends "regular" responses in the **multipart/related content-type**:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:c79210c3-bbef-4aa3-82ae-6a20c7a96564"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="application/soap+xml"
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 14:11:25 GMT
Content-Length: 658

--uuid:c79210c3-bbef-4aa3-82ae-6a20c7a96564
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="application/soap+xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">...
```

This leads to a ProtocolException in the WCF client because the **WCF client does not expect a multipart/related answer**. The ProtocolException message is (in German):

> Der Inhaltstyp "multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";
>   boundary="uuid:ead716a3-4b8b-4207-ad66-b9f18ae368b2";
>   start="";
>   start-info="application/soap+xml"" der Antwortnachricht stimmt nicht
>   mit dem Inhaltstyp der Bindung (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)
>   überein. Wenn Sie einen benutzerdefinierten Encoder verwenden, sollten
>   Sie sicherstellen, dass die IsContentTypeSupported-Methode korrekt
>   implementiert ist. Die ersten 1024 Bytes der Antwort waren: ...

In English:

> The content type "multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";
>   boundary="uuid:ead716a3-4b8b-4207-ad66-b9f18ae368b2";
>   start="";
>   start-info="application/soap+xml"" of the response message
>   does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the
>   IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 1024
>   bytes of the response were: ...

Does anyone have an idea how I can consume this multipart/related message with a WCF client (without using the HttpWebRequest class)? Is there any configuration available for this szenario?

Comment: Did you try to switch from `text` to `Mtom` to encode SOAP messages? Config: `<binding messageEncoding="Mtom">` / Code: `binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;`

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to change anything. (I'll add the binding info to my question)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Max' and Mehmet's hints showed the right direction but I had to change a bit more.
Since I used the  element in , the wcf configuration ignored the messageEncoding="Mtom" attribute.

Instead of using attribute, it seems better to use the  element directly:

```
<binding name="energylinkSOAP">
    <mtomMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
    <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
</binding>
```

By that you also can define more configurations, such as messageVersion.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for. If you're trying to consume Oracle ADF Services, and do so through a proxy, they may succeed but .NET will throw an exception about the response type. Doing this programatically ([binding].MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom;) solved my problem.

Comment: @Tor how did you set the MessageEncoding? Do you still have the code? For the Mtom binding I only seeing readerQuotas and writeEncoding. Did you use customBinding or wsHttpBinding?

Answer (score 1):

I think that converting system into to MTOM will work for that.

Comment: Hi Mehmet, I expected that, too but it does not change a thing, if I add messageEncoding="Mtom" to <binding name="abcSoap">